# Spring Expression Language - set different value if Profile is set

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, spring-profiles

I have a class like this:

```
public AbstractConfig() {
    super(DataConfig.MGR_NAME);
}
```

Inside `DataConfig` there is:

```
    public final String MGR_NAME = "theManager";
```

I find SpEL documentation confusing.  Is there a way I can change a value if a Spring Profile is set?  That is, if I have the Profile "AlternateManager" use `theManagerAlt`, but default to `theManager` otherwise?

While I made up this notation to get an active profile, I am hoping there exists some syntax like that below to make this work:

```
    @Value("#PROFILE['AlternateManager'] ? 'theManagerAlt' : 'theManager' ")
    public final String MGR_NAME;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ANSWER:**

After a lot of googling and playing around, finally found it.  Hopefully, this will be of use to others!  This works:

```
@Value("#{environment.acceptsProfiles('AlternateManager') ? 'theManagerAlt' : 'theManager' }")
```

The `String` can not be `final`, but I can live with that.

Seems a shame to me that this is not documented well.
This OLD ticket: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9037 linked me to an old SO question which gave me the answer.

That ticket is essentially a request for better documentation.
IMO, everyone should vote for that OPEN, 6-year-old ticket.

Answer (score 0):

If AlternateManager is set use it otherwise use the manager(default)

```
@Value("#{PROFILE['AlternateManager'] ?: 'theManager' }")
public final String MGR_NAME;
```

Comment: If it wasn't clear, I think I made up that notation of "PROFILE" - it is not in the docs anywhere I could find.  I tried your suggested syntax anyway and it blows up when trying to process "PROFILE"

Comment: Please refer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-defaults. 5.Using SpEL

Comment: Yes, that tells how to get a value from any system properties that were set.  My question is can you use the setting of a Spring profile as a boolean (i.e. whether or not a given profile is 'active') within a SpEL expression.  I can't figure out how...

Comment: Based on what your trying to do I suggest looking into @ ConditionalOnProperty or @ ConditionalOnExpression or defining custom Conditions to set the property.

Answer (score 0):

If AbstractConfig is a Spring bean, you can write a Configuration class in which you initialize the bean with the expected parameter depending on whether your 'AlternateManager' profile is active or not :

```
@Configuration
public class ExampleConfiguration {

  // If AlternateManager profile is enabled, Spring Bean will be initialized with "theManagerAlt"
  @Bean
  @Profile("AlternateManager")
  public AbstractConfig getDevDataSource() {
    return new AbstractConfig("theManagerAlt");
  }

  // if AlternateManager profile is not enabled, Spring Bean will be initialized with "theManager"
  @Bean
  @Profile("!AlternateManager")
  public AbstractConfig getProdDataSource() {
      return new AbstractConfig("theManager");
  }
}
```

Comment: Gave you the bounty because I didn't want it to go to waste - it would have simply expired otherwise!   Your answer pointed me towards some better searching that I think helped me find the answer in the end!

Comment: Glad to know that I could help you. And thank you for the bounty!